# error. TypeError: object with buffer protocol also requires urequest

Tags: telegram, esp32, micropython

Hola comunidad  estos haciendo un programa de mensaje de alerta desde la esp32 con micropython a telegram en thonny.

```
import urequests 
if (wifi.isconnected()): print('connected') 
   urequests.post('https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxxxx:xxxxxxx/sendMessage', data={'chat_id': 
   'xxxxxxxx', 'text': 'hello from esp'}) print('message sent')
```

Al compilarlo me aparece el siguiente error:

> error: Traceback (most recent last call): File "", line 8, in # File "requests/init.py", line 184, in post File "requests/init.py", line 123, in request

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar el código completo para poder reproducir el error?

Comment: Ese el código completo camarada. Solo falta la conexión a wifi

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que el diccionario no soporta el [buffer protocol](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/05/05/introduction-to-the-python-buffer-protocol/). Para corregir el problema se puede convertir en una cadena:

```
import urequests
import json
payload = {'chat_id': 'xxxxxxxx', 'text': 'hello from esp'}
data = (json.dumps(payload)).encode()
urequests.post('https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxxxx:xxxxxxx/sendMessage', data=data)
print('message sent')
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda pero todavia sigo con problemas en codigo .   {'description': 'Bad Request: message text is empty', 'ok': False, 'error_code': 400} al imprimir